# openssl 'genpkey -algorithm RSA' vs. 'genrsa'

Tags: openssl

What is difference between below two commands?
1. openssl **genpkey -algorithm RSA**
2. openssl **genrsa**

In document difference is **"Private Key"** and **"RSA Private Key"**.

Then..
What is diference between **"Private Key with algorithm RSA"** and **"RSA Private Key"**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `genpkey` command can create other types of private keys - DSA, DH, EC and maybe GOST - whereas the `genrsa`, as it's name implies, only generates RSA keys. There are equivalent `gendh` and `gendsa` commands.

However, the OpenSSL documentation states that these `gen*` commands have been superseded by the generic `genpkey` command.

In the case of your examples, both generate RSA private keys.

```
openssl genrsa -out genrsa.key 2048
```

and

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out genpkey.key
```

will generate a 2048 bit RSA key with the exponent set to 65537.

Simply `cat` the resulting files to see that they are both PEM format private keys; although `openssl rsa` encloses them in `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` and `END RSA PRIVATE KEY` while `openssl genpkey` omits the `RSA`.  The former is [PKCS#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) format, while the latter is [PKCS#8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8).

Running `openssl rsa text -in <filename>` against both shows that they are RSA private keys with the same `publicExponent`. The newer `genpkey` command has the option to change this using `-pkeyopt rsa_keygen_pubexp:value` while the `genrsa` command doesn't have this option.

Comment: The difference in the output files is the difference between 'traditional' or 'legacy' format written by `genrsa` (and also `rsa`) and 'new' (since about 2000) PKCS8 format written by `genpkey` (and also `pkey` and `pkcs8 -topk8`); although they contain semantically the same information they are not the same and the PEM label `RSA PRIVATE KEY` vs `PRIVATE KEY` is very important. Also if they are password-encrypted (your example is not) the PBE used is _very_ different (PKCS8 is better). There is no commandline `gendh` -- and EC-specific gen is inconsistently `ecparam -genkey` !

Comment: Thank you.. Then, difference is format and genrsa is more legacy way right?
So then, is **genpkey -algorithm RSA** the better way to generate RSA key then **genrsa**?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Thank you for the update.  I've edited my answer to add PKCS#1 & #8. `gendh` is listed as an option to `openssl help`.  That's as far as I've tried it though!

Comment: You're right, I wrote that too fast and skipped a bit; sorry. `gendh` _and_ `gendsa` generate _parameters_ (aka groups) not keys, equivalent to new-style `genpkey -genparam` ; `dsaparam -genkey` and `ecparam -genkey` generate keys for given parameters but there is no old-style way to generate a DH _key_ (for any parameters), only new-style `genpkey` (without `-genparam`) can do a DH key.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Exim with DKIM support does not directly accept RSA private keys generated by the `openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa ...` command. Exim expects the private key to use the `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` and `END RSA PRIVATE KEY` delimiter lines, as generated by `openssl genrsa ...`, and not `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`/`END PRIVATE KEY` as generated with `openssl genpkey ...`.

Exim will fail with the message `DKIM: signing failed (RC -101)` in the panic log when sending mail if the delimiter lines are wrong.

Comment: This problem may be limited to earlier Exim versions. A server running Exim 4.91 (linked to OpenSSL 1.1.0h) is using a `genpkey` DKIM key with `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY / END PRIVATE KEY` delimiters. Exim is using this key to sign outgoing SMTP without any problems.